# Python can recognize header position and extract header info

Tags: python, pandas, data-science, visualization

I have a csv file in which there are 3 or more headers in one csv file. I want python or pandas to be able to recognize the header position and extract the header info in the csv file. Here I give an example of a csv file that I have.

```
"Level and Distortion",,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
"Ch1 (F)",,"Ch1 (H2)",,"Ch1 (H3)",,"Ch1 (Total)",,"Ch2 (F)",,"Ch2 (H2)",,"Ch2 (H3)",,"Ch2 (Total)",
X,Y,X,Y,X,Y,X,Y,X,Y,X,Y,X,Y,X,Y
Hz,Vrms,Hz,Vrms,Hz,Vrms,Hz,Vrms,Hz,Vrms,Hz,Vrms,Hz,Vrms,Hz,Vrms
20,0.00772013164376534,20,5.60982648239952E-05,20,0.000389709733151927,20,0.011492581958802,20,0.00699792689186063,20,0.000151471712877565,20,0.000389940899485093,20,0.010080448380793
..
..
"THD Ratio",,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
Ch1,,Ch2,,,,,,,,,,,,,
X,Y,X,Y,,,,,,,,,,,,
Hz,%,Hz,%,,,,,,,,,,,,
20,83.009797319554,20,82.1460991930652,,,,,,,,,,,,
21.1179638886716,85.3656629417084,21.1179638886716,82.0338466400102,,,,,,,,,,,,
..
..
"Reference Waveform",,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
Ch1,,Ch2,,,,,,,,,,,,,
X,Y,X,Y,,,,,,,,,,,,
s,V,s,V,,,,,,,,,,,,
0,0,0,0,,,,,,,,,,,,
2.08333333333333E-05,6.47890208369956E-08,2.08333333333333E-05,6.47890208369956E-08,,,,,,,,,,,,
```

I want python to be able to recognize header position automatically.

Comment: Actually there are very many numeric values in the csv file data.

Comment: I believe that you need to iterate on the CSV file line by line to achieve that, read the whole CSV, using pd.read_csv, then with a for loop, you could extract each header with its data aside.

Comment: Can u give an example a little.

Comment: I don't think the `csv` module or pandas will do this automatically. They'll only use the first line of the file automatically as the header. If you want to process each section as a separate file, you'll need to code this yourself. It's hard to see how we can write an "example" that isn't the whole thing.

Comment: @Barmar you need to see my csv file?

Comment: i realy need help

Comment: I can see it in the question. If you aren't able to program this yourself, you need to find someone to do it for you. We'll help you fix the code for you, we won't write it for you.

Comment: Okey, i will back

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do it with [`read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) and a very basic *regex* approach :

```
import re
from io import StringIO

with open("file.csv") as f:
    d = {m.group(1).split(",")[0].strip('"'): 
           (pd.read_csv(StringIO(m.group(2)), header=[0,1,2]).dropna(how="all", axis=1))
         for m in re.finditer("(.*?)\n(.*?)(\n..\n..\n|$)", f.read(), flags=re.DOTALL)}
```

Output :

`d` is a `dict` where the keys are the sub-csv/tables names :

```
print(d.keys())

#dict_keys(['Level and Distortion', 'THD Ratio', 'Reference Waveform'])
```

---

.. and the values are a [*DataFrame*](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html). To access one of the dataframes, use *dictionnary-key* indexing :
​

```
print(d["THD Ratio"])

    Ch1 Unnamed: 1_level_0   Ch2 Unnamed: 3_level_0
      X                  Y     X                  Y
     Hz                  %    Hz                  %
0 20.00              83.01 20.00              82.15
1 21.12              85.37 21.12              82.03
```

Comment: **NB**: The resulting DataFrame has a [*MultiIndex*](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.html) that you can readapt with [`droplevel`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.droplevel.html) *and/or* [`set_axis`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_axis.html).